# How to center stacked elements with boostrap and CSS sprite elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-sprites

How to center content of 5 elements with Boostrap after they are stacked one on top of the other considering the elements are made with CSS sprites?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row benefitRow">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-1 iconThumb"><p class="benefitText">text</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-2  iconPackage"> <p class="benefitText">text</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-2 iconFree"><p class="benefitText">text</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-2 iconBox"><p class="benefitText">text</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 iconCouch"><p class="benefitText">text</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

--> [View Example](http://codepen.io/Adrenaline22/pen/ggdjQL)

Comment: Sorry @peter pupovac. With seeing your example i found that what thing made me misunderstanding.

Comment: not centered -> [http://imgur.com/a/5or4i]

Answer (score 0):

Please test this one:

```
.col-lg-2 {
    background-size: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-height: 49px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-position-x: 25%;
 }
```

Comment: I tried to add, but the elements do not move. Could you please check it yourself? btw..thanks for contributing

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: Chrome. Can you fork it in a working pen? I tried all the variations in the console (webkit, non webkit etc.)..ti still does not center the damn divs.

Comment: Yes it is just here, and this new edit of answer works. Please test this one and give me the result.

Comment: I want the elements to be centered when they are stacked one on top of the other (for example XS). They were perfectly fine in LG/MD. Although I must admit that now they're little bitter than before thanks to you.

Comment: Would you please test this. It was better you firstly mentioned the browser size. Thanks.